# how to get data from two room tables without relation then post it to retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow

I am writing android application with kotlin.

I have make repository to get list of data from two table that don't have relation, I want to post the results to retrofit. what is the best way to do it?
This is my snippet code:

```
val listKaryawanLocalEntity = repository.local.getDataDescLocal().asLiveData()
val logAllAbsen: LiveData<List<AbsenEntity>> = repository.local.getAllAbsensi().asLiveData()
```

I want to post both of list using retrofit

usually I observe for result, but it only support one object